# OnClick() isn't working

Tags: java, android, onclick, onclicklistener

I'm having trouble taking in text from a few text boxes with one button. I can't seem to get OnClick() to work. I have  setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_xactivity); as a test I know it doesn't have anything to do with input.

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.create);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(View v){
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_xactivity);
     }
});
```

Is in my protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState). Doesn't work. No errors, just doesn't do anything.

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.create);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home2);
    }
});
```

On It's own Doesn't resolve setOnClickListener. I have import android.view.View.OnClickListener set. I've tried entering different code where it says setContentView(R.layout.activity_home2);

Comment: You should try with a simple log statement or a `Toast` instead of a  `setContentView`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setContentView() is not enough to switch between layouts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605437/setcontentview-is-not-enough-to-switch-between-layouts)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an `ID` to the `Layout` holding the `Views, Buttons` (`RelativeLayout`, `ContrasintLayout` ect...) in XML. Then in java make a `new Layout`, and use `layout.addContentView(XML)` in your button:

```
Layout a = findViewById(R.id.layout_name);//Use whatever layout TYPE is used in XML

Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.create);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
  public void onClick(View v){
    a.addContentView(R.layout.activity_load_xactivity);
 }
});
```

Also, In you XML, you should give an ID to your layout then define it in java.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/layout_name">
 <!--You can use any Layout Type -->                                                      
 ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

I know this has nothing to with your question, but if you want to switch activity's use this instead:

```
Intent b = new Intent(this, JavaActivtyName.class);
startActivity(b);
```